# Is the Star Trek warp drive canonically the Alcubierre drive?

Tags: star-trek, canon, ftl-drive

The [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) is frequently referred to in any and all discussion about FTL travel as "the Star Trek drive", but is there any in-universe evidence to suggest that the principles are at all similar?

Are the principles and workings of the Warp Drive shown at all in-universe, and if so, is there any similarity to that of the Alcubierre theory?

Comment: Two questions--first, do you want to restrict the question to TV canon, or would stuff from works created by one of the TV shows' technical consultants, like the [TNG Technical Manual](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual), be relevant? Second, are you also interested in the question of whether it would be possible or impossible to reconcile in-universe descriptions of the workings of Trek warp drive with the Alcubierre drive (possibly combined with some other mainstream physics ideas)? I have some thoughts on that but could make a diff question...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Not canonically.

The *Star Trek* warp drive has some features in common with the Alcubierre drive, a theoretical faster-than-light drive proposed by physicist Miguel Alcubierre in 1994.  There is no canonical statement by producers or writers of the series to suggest that the warp drive is the Alcubierre drive.

From the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) on the Alcubierre drive:

> The Star Trek television series used the term "warp drive" to describe their method of faster-than-light travel. Neither the Alcubierre theory, nor anything similar, existed when the series was conceived, but Alcubierre stated in an email to William Shatner that his theory was directly inspired by the term used in the show, and references it in his 1994 paper.

In particular, the Alcubierre drive uses a **"warp bubble"**.

[image]

From the same article:

> The ship would then ride this wave inside a region of flat space, known as a warp bubble, and would not move within this bubble but instead be carried along as the region itself moves due to the actions of the drive.

As it stands, the Alcubierre metric is the best model we currently have for understanding *Star Trek*'s warp drive at a mathematical / general relativistic level. (Caution:  being the best model does not mean it is a *good* model).

Comment: Sadly, the Alcubierre drive [wouldn't work as advertised](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119522/) (among other [discussions on PSE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=alcubierre+drive+is%3Aq)), so I'd argue that it's not even *a model* of warp drives.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - which statement in that link are you referring to when you say it "wouldn't work as advertised"? I thought the consensus was that it would work in general relativity, although there are reasons to *suspect* that in quantum gravity some effects related to the [chronology protection conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_protection_conjecture) would kick in and prevent it from allowing FTL travel (though it's possible it would only kick in with specific situations involving multiple warp bubbles that would allow for time travel, which a single lone bubble doesn't).

Comment: @Hypnosifl: The Alcubierre drive doesn't allow FTL travel, which is kinda a requirement for a model of the [ST warp drive](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Warp_drive).

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - No GR solution allows one to *locally* travel faster than light, is that all you mean? But it does allow one to do what we see on Star Trek, get to distant stars and back home in a much shorter time than it would take a beam of light that wasn't itself within the warp bubble (or wasn't itself traveling through the wormhole). In this sense, there isn't really any clear evidence that Star Trek ships travel *locally* faster than light either, speeds may just be expressed relative to the approximately flat part of spacetime outside the bubble.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: With the AD, you'd get to Alpha Cen in 14 days but everyone else not in the bubble ages the 817 years (as per the first answer I linked). This is clearly **not** what happens in ST, so this cannot be a model for a ST-esque warp drive in the least.

Comment: @KyleKanos: however, in the edit in the middle of that answer the poster admits he was mistaken.  It takes 14 days for the ship to reach Alpha Centauri *as measured from Earth* not just from the POV of those inside the bubble.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Looking back & crunching the numbers, I do think his math is mistaken, it should be ~4 years and not 817, which is still a long shot from the 14 days that you're somehow claiming is stated as being for the rest-frame POV (which I would think would violate causality & be contrary to relativity).

Comment: @KyleKanos: I took the figure of 14 days from the linked answer.  The Alcubierre drive is not contrary to relativity, in fact it is based on the mathematics of General Relativity.  It does however violate causality, which is is usually interpreted as evidence that the negative energy required by the drive can't exist.  (The Wikipedia article covers all of this.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: I didn't say Alcubierre drive was contrary to relativity (you are talking to an astrophysicist here), I said that your interpretation of 14 days in (what I read as implying) *both* frames would be contrary to relativity.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - It does violate causality if you have multiple alcubierre bubbles as shown in [this paper](http://exvacuo.free.fr/div/Sciences/Dossiers/Time/A%20E%20Everett%20-%20Warp%20drive%20and%20causality%20-%20prd950914.pdf), but there are many known solutions in general relativity that violate causality, such as [traversable wormholes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Time_travel) and the [Godel metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel_metric). Physicists think it's likely this will be ruled out in quantum gravity, but in general relativity alone this allowable.

Comment: @KyleKanos, no such assertion was intended.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - *Why* do you think it would violate relativity for the time to be 14 days in both frames, if not because of the causality violation? If you build a wormhole to Alpha Centauri, it's certainly possible to arrange things so that the proper time experienced by an observer traveling through the wormhole from Earth to Alpha Centauri is identical to the time measured by observers on Earth and Alpha Centauri for the observer to get from one to the other, using an inertial frame outside the wormhole (assuming a solution where spacetime is flat outside the wormhole mouths).

Comment: @Hypnosifl: For two observers to agree on a dt, they have to be co-moving (remember that the AD is a local perturbation on a Minkowski spacetime, so we can use SR here). Either the AD doesn't work *or* the elapsed time is different.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - You can use SR for observers far outside the bubble since the solution is asymptotically flat, but I don't see why you can use them for observers within the bubble since the metric departs significantly from SR on its boundary. Also, I found confirmation that observers outside the bubble would measure it to get to distant locations faster than light outside--p. 117 of physicist Allen Everett's book "Time Travel and Warp Drives" says "The bubble and its contents could travel through spacetime at a speed faster than light, as seen by observers outside the bubble."

Comment: (continued) And given that the bubble can travel faster than light as measured outside, you obviously can't use the SR time dilation equation to figure out how much time is experienced inside the bubble, since that equation doesn't give meaningful answers when v exceeds c.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - I have updated [my own answer](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/146201/59406) to the question in your "wouldn't work as advertised" link, explaining in the last two paragraphs of my answer why I think the top-rated answer by dolphus333 is making an error in the calculation of the time measured by external observers--if you have time please take a look and let me know if you disagree with my comments there.

Comment: Interestingly, ST:TNG invokes the term "warp bubble" in the 1990 episode "Remember Me", also pre-dating Alcubierre's publication, although the concept to which it is attached seems a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the star trek drive creates a warp bubble that pushes the ship into a layer of subspace or something to that effect (which is why the omega particle and the damaging of subspace are plot points in certain episodes)

Alcubierre was inspired by the star trek description of a warp drive but the star trek warp drive is not technically an Alcubierre drive

Answer (score 1):

No.

The Alcubierre drive makes use of a supply of negative energy whose gravitation creates a carefully shaped distortion in the space-time of General Relativity, nicknamed a "warp bubble" because Alcubierre was a Star Trek fan.

The [Star Trek drive](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Warp_drive) uses field coils to generate a warp field which in turn form a subspace bubble.  Our current model of physics does not include either warp fields or subspace.  There is no tradition in science fiction of using the word "subspace" to mean distortions in space-time, and as far as I know there is no indication in Star Trek canon of any direct connection between the warp drive and the various space-time distortions that they do come across.

In addition to the incompatible terminology, there are some explicit discrepancies:

- There is no indication in canon that the Star Trek drive requires a supply of negative energy.  If a supply of negative energy were required it would surely have been mentioned at some point.  *Note: antimatter has positive energy, just like ordinary matter.*
- Conversely, an Alcubierre drive does not require a supply of antimatter like a Star Trek warp drive does.
- I believe an Alcubierre ship has a net mass of zero, so would not be directly affected by gravity even when the drives were off.  In such a ship, it should (for example) be easy to avoid crash-landing on a planet.  Ahem.
- It is clear that in Star Trek there is an absolute rest frame, i.e., a meaningful "now" that applies at least throughout the galaxy, and that warp drive speeds are relative to the rest frame.  While warp drives [can be used to violate causality](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home) they do not do so as a matter of course.  The theory of the Alcubierre drive does not allow for this, and in fact the lack of any obvious mechanism to resist causality violations is perhaps the primary criticism leveled at the concept.

Comment: There might be a way around the negative mass issue--physicist Kip Thorne says in his book *The Science of Interstellar* that in certain theories with where our universe is a kind of 3D membrane sitting in a higher-dimensional space, which physicists call the "bulk", manipulating "bulk fields" in the higher dimension could allow for certain tricks that would be impossible if the 3 dimensions of space that we know are all that exist--one of these tricks would be changing the value of the gravitational constant, and he says another would be holding a wormhole open without exotic matter.

Comment: (continued) ...and this could fit with Star Trek in certain ways, since we know warp drive depends on manipulating the "subspace field", and certain episodes seem to hint at the idea of subspace being another dimension, like [Schisms](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Schisms_(episode)) where the Enterprise crew was being kidnapped by beings that lived in a different "subspace manifold" (with 'manifold' ordinarily referring to a type of surface, including the 3D surface of our universe in the [brane cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) I mentioned).